# Jhipster JDL Is There CI-CD language that can be used in the JDL Like Deployment

Tags: jhipster, gitlab-ci, jdl

I noticed that the generator supports jhipster ci-cd & the jdl supports deployment, but could not find any documentation on whether the jdl supports ci-cd & if it does what the language is.  Seems this would be part of the documentation and JDL if available via the generator?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is out of scope for the JDL (at least currently), it describes itself as handling ["your applications, deployments, entities and their relationships"](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/)

Here is the [parser for the JDL language](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-core/blob/master/lib/dsl/jdl_parser.js) and I don't see anything regarding continuous integration, so I don't think it's an undocumented feature.

You could make the [feature request here](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-core/issues)